How to win this endgame cleanest?
A couple of days ago I played a game OTB and the following endgame occured:
[Title "White to move"]
[FEN "4b3/8/6p1/1pnk4/p4BP1/P1P1K2P/2B5/8 w - - 0 1"]

It is still not clear to me, how to systematically play for a win without allowing counterplay for black. In my opinion, black might get counterplay, if his king can attack our queenside pawns successfully.
I think white should try to get an outside passed pawn on the kingside. But this doesn't seem to be so easy in practice: The black bishop is controlling h5, such that the advance h5-h6 must be supported by the white king or the white bishop. In each case black seems to get counterplay.
Can someone help me finding the right plan for white?

This situation is quite complex. Not an answer, but I think you need to systematically and continuously check the opponent while not losing any pieces. Force the king away from the knight and pawns, so that those pieces will be weakly protected. Then forces a trade of bishops, g and h file pawns to move. Take the b file black pawn from the back using the king (get there first before opponent king occupies the position), and since the other pawn is blocked by your own pawn it can't promote. The rest is easy: protect the g and h file pawns with both remaining bishop and king.

Since there are two pawns they can protect each other too. So basically you only need to protect the unprotected pawn (the one behind). After promotion force opponent's king into a corner and then checkmate. However I didn't write an answer since I don't know the specifics steps and order in which steps are carried out. But this plan is probably going to win the game.

Engine says: Ignore attacks on your queen pawns, they hold for long enough so your own pawns (after K->g5, Bxg6) will queen first. (Sacrifice a bishop if necessary.) Computer thus suggests passive defense of Black, but that of course is hopeless in the long run.
